# Printing barcode in Acumatica reports

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to modify the picklist report and add a barcode, which uses the shipping number.

If i select Barcode and table field in the value propery. I am getting error object reference is not set to instance of an object.

How to print Barcode using table filed value?

[image]

If I set Source as Barcode then I am getting the following error

```
Error:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.      Send
```

Raised At: 10/27/2016 12:34:57 PM   Screen: SO.64.40.00
   Details: 
10/27/2016 12:34:57 PM Error: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[image]

If I change it to database, there is no error but it is not displaying barcode

Comment: Can you upload your .rpx file somewhere and share the link here for review?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3x2p89psai5iipi/so644000.rps?dl=0

Comment: This is the .rps file - only a shortcut to report. You need to do File->Save As from report designer.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8fu1o347zb4xmt/so644000.rpx?dl=0

Comment: Report opens just fine - what is the detailed exception?

Answer (score 2):

I am just posting the answer as given by Acumatica Support, so that this could help someone in the future.

1. Use Barcode type: Code128
2. Use MimeType : image/bmp
3. Source : Barcode
4. In the value field, ensure "=" is not used.

Regards

Nandakumar S